# Content Porter to publication with different name

Tags: tridion, tridion2009, tridion-content-delivery

While exporting content from a publication to a publication with different name in other environment, then the properties are also becoming same for target publication and we are not able to change the parents for the target publication. Need help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's quite a few technical ways to achieve this... but my preferred method is to temporarily rename either the source or the target publication so that the names match.

Comment: I have exported the website(Publication). IN the publication where I am importing there I want to inherit content from some other publication not from that one which is parent of the publication from which export is done. This is creating the problem

Comment: Does treating the imports from each publication separately work?

Comment: And if you rename your parent publication(s) to match? Yes, they should match between environments. You can try playing with URI mappings in mappings.xml, but frankly I've always found it easier to ensure the publications name match.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to import content into publication, but do not update publication itself. That's possible to do, but a bit tricky:

1. Open DependencyFilters.xml. Make sure you have Publication dependency filter in the Structure dependency filters group (by default it isn’t included in any group, so add it).
2. Select your package and open its mappings file. Set ImportTitle of the publication to the title of publication you are importing to.
3. On Dependency Filters screen enable Structure dependency filters group.
4. On the Select Items screen select items you need to import inside publication, but deselect publication itself.
5. Do import.